# ComboBoxViewerCellEditor and AutoCompleteField doesn't work

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a ComboBoxViewerCellEditor that has an AutoCompleteField.

I defined it as:

```
new AutoCompleteField(cellEditor.getControl(),new CComboContentAdapter(),values);
```

The autocomplete values are showing and my combo is selecting a value if I select it via keyboard. Problem is when I double click with my mouse on the prefilled list. This doesn't have any impact on the combo, it doesn't select the value.

Is there something I am missing? Should I add some listener?

Thank you,

Luisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you are selecting it from mouse your focus is lost from the cell editor, thats why it is not affecting.

cell editor has one method something like dependsOnexternalFocus() . It by default return true. Override it and return false from it.

Inside constructor of your cell editor class create your own content adapter and place code below:

```
    contentProposalAdapter.addContentProposalListener(new IContentProposalListener2()
    {

        public void proposalPopupClosed(ContentProposalAdapter adapter)
        {
            popupOpen = false;
        }

        public void proposalPopupOpened(ContentProposalAdapter adapter)
        {
            popupOpen = true;
        }
    });
```

and override

```
 @Override
    protected void focusLost()
    {
        if (!popupOpen)
        {
            super.focusLost();
        }
    }
```

popupOpen is private boolean type variable.

Comment: I override the  dependsOnExternalFocusListener() but it doesn't enter there when I use the mouse. Maybe I should also tell that I am using this CellEditor within an ObservableValueEditingSupport subclass (in the getCellEditor() method). In the doCreateCellEditorObservable, I return a ViewersObservable.observeSingleSelection(comboCellEditor.getViewer()). Should I modify this to behave differently? Thank you